# How to process text in shell script and assign to varibles?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

sample.text file .

```
var1=https://www.process.com
var2=https://www.hp.com
var3=http://www.google.com
:
:

varz=https://www.sample.com
```

i am sending this sample txt as input to one script.
that script should split the lines and assign the variables to diff parameters

like

```
$varn= $var1,....$varn
$value=https://www.sample.com ( all the variables value)
```

i am trying with below script not working .

```
#!/bin/bash
for $1 in ( cat sample.txt );
do 
 echo $1 #var1=https://www.process.com
 sed 's/=/\n/g' $1 | awk 'NR%2==0'
done
```

main aim is to assign all urls to one variable and vars to one variable and process the file

Comment: Why are you not simply sourcing `sample.text`? e.g. `#!/bin/bash; source sample.txt; echo "$var1"; ...`

Comment: this is part of the script , i will do source of sample.txt , using sed 's/=/\n/g'  after split how to assign all urls to one particular variable and all var to one variable so that i can take urls info and in loop one by one and do some process

Answer (score 2):

If `sample.text` already contains your variable assignments for you, e.g.

```
var1=https://www.process.com
var2=https://www.hp.com
var3=http://www.google.com
```

and you want access to `var1, var2, ... varn`, then you are making things difficult on yourself by trying to read and parse `sample.text` instead of simply *sourcing* it with `'.'` or `source`.

For example, given `sample.text` containing:

```
$ cat sample.text
var1=https://www.process.com
var2=https://www.hp.com
var3=http://www.google.com
varz=https://www.sample.com
```

You need only source the file to access the variable, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

. sample.text || {
    printf "error sourcing sample.text\n"
    exit 1
}

printf "%s\n" $var{1..3} $varz
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash source_sample.sh
https://www.process.com
https://www.hp.com
http://www.google.com
https://www.sample.com
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.